QEMU/MULTIPASS: start failed: Another virtual machine manager is currently running. Please shut it down before starting a Multipass instance
I am trying to start multipass VM:
$ multipass start primary --verbose
but I am getting the following error:
start failed: Another virtual machine manager is currently running. Please shut it down before starting a Multipass instance.

Also, I think it might be related, as both are supposed to use QEMU,
When starting an Android VM in android-studio: I am getting the following output:
$ android-studio 
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2024-09-21 19:20:03,945 [   1582]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlags <clinit> requests com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlagSettings instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-09-21 19:20:04,297 [   1934]   WARN - #c.i.n.i.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group Logcat is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@4f240585). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=/snap/android-studio/161/plugins/android, version=241.15989.150.2411.11948838, package=null, isBundled=true)
2024-09-21 19:20:11,086 [   8723]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
2024-09-21 19:20:11,315 [   8952]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully
2024-09-21 19:20:13,761 [  11398]   WARN - #c.i.u.j.JBCefApp - JCefAppConfig.class is not from a JBR module, url: jar:file:/snap/android-studio/161/lib/lib.jar!/com/jetbrains/cef/JCefAppConfig.class (Use JBR bundled with the IDE)
2024-09-21 19:20:14,081 [  11718]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
2024-09-21 19:20:14,232 [  11869]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
2024-09-21 19:20:14,689 [  12326]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - QEMU main loop exits abnormally with code 1
2024-09-21 19:20:25,142 [  22779]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code 137
2024-09-21 19:20:25,755 [  23392]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Recently I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 (where ubuntu was asking me to remove half of the apps including nautilus to allow to go forward) and received a kernel upgrade to 6.8.0-45 (from -44)
I have a VirtualBox running on the same host but it used to work 1 week ago just fine
